# How to get class type in Kotlin Polymorphic Serialization?

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

If I have this class hierarchy:

```
@Serializable
abstract class AA

@Serializable
@SerialName("type_1")
data class A(
    val fieldA: String
) : AA()

@Serializable
@SerialName("type_2")
data class B{
   val fieldB: Boolean
} : AA()
```

When I have a list of AA classes, how can I get the type of every class? (type_1 or type_2)
For example:

```
val k: List<AA>
for(j in k) {
   j.type ??
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection API `getAnnotation` to get value. it goes like this.

```
abstract class AA

@SerialName("type_1")
data class A(
val fieldA: String
 ) : AA()

@SerialName("type_2")
data class B(val fieldB: Boolean) : AA()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val list = arrayListOf<AA>().apply {
    add(A("class A"))
    add(B(true))
}
for (j in list) {
    val serial = j.javaClass.getAnnotation(SerialName::class.java)
    println(serial.value)
}
}
```